# Onan son of Judah brother of Er reincarnated in Numbers?

Tags: genesis-bereishith, bamidbar-numbers-book-of, yehuda

I finally got to Number chapter 26 and read this:

> בְּנֵי יְהוּדָה עֵר וְאוֹנָן וַיָּמָת עֵר וְאוֹנָן בְּאֶרֶץ כְּנָעַן׃
>
> Born to Judah: Er and Onan. Er and Onan died in the land of Canaan.

Then I remembered that I read almost the same thing in Genesis 38:8

> And Judah said to Onan: Come to your brother's wife and take her in levirate marriage, and establish seed for your brother, [the son being called by the latter's name].

How is this possible? Were they reincarnated for some reason while the Israelites were on the journey?

Comment: See also Numbers 26:61.

Comment: How do these verses suggest they were reincarnated? Does reincarnation even occur?

Answer (score 8):

No. They were not reincarnated.

**Genesis 38**- they're being mentioned in the present tense of the story.

**Numbers 26**- after the plague that killed many people in Klal Yisrael (see previous chapter), the Torah takes a census of the people remaining by going through each of the 12 tribes.

Since the Torah is starting from Yehuda and discusses his descendants, Er and Onan are mentioned.

Comment: Present tense of the story? Have I been reading wrong? Does that happen a lot in Genesis? Are there other such examples of Genesis mentioning something in present tense?

Answer (score 1):

Not "on the journey," but there are indeed Kabbalistic sources that say that Er and Onan were reincarnated as Peretz and Zerach. One such source is [Pri Etz Chaim](https://www.sefaria.org/Pri_Etz_Chaim%2C_Gate_of_the_Recitation_of_the_Shema_Before_Retiring.11.32?vhe=Pri_Etz_Chaim&lang=he), by R' Chaim Vital, one of the star disciples of the Arizal.

([Ohr Hachaim, Bereishis 46:12](https://www.sefaria.org/Or_HaChaim_on_Genesis.46.12.1?vhe=On_Your_Way_&lang=he) explains somewhat differently: they were reincarnated as Chetzron and Chamul, the sons of Peretz.)